# Postgresql current_timestamp and ODBC Conection pooling

Tags: postgresql, odbc, connection-pooling

Current_timestamp returns the time of the beginning of the transaction, which is the time of the end of the previous transaction.

But what happens for connection pooling?  The commit may have happened long ago at the end of some previous and unrelated transaction.

(And is connection pooling really necessary in postgresql anyway?  It is a nasty hack to overcome slow connection open times which should be very fast if the TLS connection is reused.)

Comment: Creating the network connection is the cheap part. Starting the backend process and loading the catalog caches is what makes it expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Current_timestamp returns the time of the beginning of the
> transaction, which is the time of the end of the previous transaction.

Why? This is an incorrect description.

[CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) return the start time of the *current* transaction. Always. It is not possible to query `select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` without opening a transaction, but such a transaction can be opened and committed implicitly, only for one specific request.

Comment: I think the key thing is that Autocommit=false is not really a concept in Postgres.  It is always autocommit unless there is a begin.